# ASP expected END error 800a03f6

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

asp newbie here. i keep getting this error,

Expected 'End'

/BusMaintenance/v1/submit.asp, line 40

in the following (really simple) code. The sole purpose of this is to take a form submit from another page and add it to the database.

```
<!--METADATA
TYPE="TypeLib"
NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library"
UUID="{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}"
VERSION="2.6"
-->
<!--#include file="../conf/adovbs.inc"-->
<!--#include file="../conf/conf_asp.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../inc/system/library.inc"-->
<!--#include file="../inc/system/signedHeader.asp"-->

<%  
    Dim adoCon
    Dim rsAddResults
    Dim strSQL

    Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=E:\wwwroot\dev_sites\BusMaintenance\db\FMS.mdb;"

    Set rsAddResults = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    strSQL = "SELECT TestTable.UserName, TestTable.Position FROM TestTable;"

    rsAddResults.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    rsAddResults = selSQL(strSQL)

    rsAddResults.AddNew

    rsAddResults.Fields("UserName")= Request.Form("UserName")
    rsAddResults.Fields("Position")= Request.Form("Position")

    rsAddResults.Update

    'rsAddResults.Close 
    'adoCon.Close
    'Set rsAddResults = Nothing
    'Set adoCon = Nothing   

    Response.Redirect "index.asp"
%>
```

I've quadruple checked it but I can't spot the problem. Seems to be a syntax error but ???

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your include files aswell. It seems like there might be a 'Function ...()' without an 'End Function' somewhere, or an 'If' without 'End If'. It's propably in the includes.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Other files with identical included files (and borderline identical code) run just fine. There is something in here!

Comment: :) I'd try removing all includes first, adding them one by one. After that do the same with the code. Just comment everything out and re-enable it line by line. You should be able to find the cause that way...

Comment: I can't see any conditional or looping code in there that would need an End. You could try commenting out lines until it works.

Comment: Tried commenting out lines as you guys suggested but couldn't find the error. I've moved around this instead of through it so I suppose the question is moot. Is there a way to close a question?